# Attaching SharePoint databases on a lower SQL version

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql-server, content-database

Searched the interwebz for this but couldn't find any info. I've got two SharePoint 2013 environments. SharePoint is upgraded to the same version on both. SQL Server versions are different, though: one SQL server is on 2012 SP2, while another is on 2012 SP3. Would detach/attach still work properly when moving databases from SQL Server 2012 SP3 to SQL Server 2012 SP2?

Answer (score 1):

"Migrating up or down service pack levels on the same SQL Server version is generally OK, because the internal database version number usually does not change."

[Source](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97081/restoring-database-between-different-version-of-sql-server-softwareversionbuild)

Answer (score 1):

As a short answer : Yes Because it's the same SQL version and you will not need to do a `downgrade copy database` ! so The restore should be worked fine .